# how to force drupal to create tables with ENGINE=MyISAM

Tags: 7, database

this is a popular error in drupal that you guys might have seen this before :

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found, table .... does not exist.
```

when I'm trying to install drupal7, it reports an error that semaphore table does not exist. I tried to create it manually by this query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `semaphore` (
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique name.',
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'A value for the semaphore.',
  `expire` double NOT NULL COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp with microseconds indicating when the semaphore should expire.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `value` (`value`),
  KEY `expire` (`expire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Table for holding semaphores, locks, flags, etc. that...';
```

it reported the same error. I changed `InnoDB` to `myISAM` and it worked!!! 
I found out that tables with the `InnoDB` engine are not supported in mysql on the server and unfortunately drupal7 creates all the tables with this engine by default. is there any way to change this default to `MyISAM` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema definitions can take an argument of `'mysql_engine'`, which defaults to 'InnoDB', in [createTableSql()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!mysql!schema.inc/function/DatabaseSchema_mysql%3A%3AcreateTableSql/7).

In theory you could thus [alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7) all the defined schemas with a custom module, and change the engine.

It's **highly questionable** to do so though. If you value your site and data, you should **NOT** use MyISAM unless you understand the difference the two engines.

Switch to a provider that supports InnoDB instead. MySQL itself [defaults to InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-default-se.html) as of 5.5. I would be very suspicious of any provider that didn't support InnoDB.

Comment: from performance perspective InnoDB seems to be superior to MyISAM, but when the whole website is down because of engine-type, performance does not matter at all

Comment: @Mohammad but MyISAM is more likely to malfunct in a way that would take your website down.

Comment: @Mołot you are right but what can I do when website doesn't work with InnoDB? I would be happy if it worked with InnoDB but even the `localhost` reports the above mentioned error.

Comment: @Mohammad I am not sure if Drupal 7 will work properly with MyISAM.  InnoDB is [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant, while MyISAM isn't.  You may need to dig around to see if Drupal 7 database transactions will still work reliably.

Comment: @Mohammad if your code is trying to access tables in some obsolete way, you fix the code, not downgrade server.

Comment: @Mołot I completely removed the codes, there was no code on server I just imported the database on server. it imported the tables ; the tables were displayed in the tree structure of phpmyadmin (under the database name) but when I clicked on them to see their content it reported the error that table doesn't exists! I changed it `engine` and it worked! it means mysql-server can't analyse InnoDB.

Comment: @MPD I contacted the server administrator and asked them to insert this code into `my.ini` or `my.cnf` of mysql-server: `innodb_file_per_table=1`. they did this and nothing worked. you are right, from performance perspective InnoDB is better

Answer (score 0):

Try this way: (from here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1089724 )

> In includes>database>mysql>shema.inc, on line 84, I changed
>   'mysql_engine' => 'InnoDB' to 'mysql_engine' => 'MyISAM'.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Define 'mysql_engine' => 'MyISAM' in your hook_schima as given below:

```
function hook_schema() {
$schema['table_name'] = array(
'description' => 'Your description.',
'fields' => array(
  'id' => array(
    'description' => 'Auto increment id.',
    'type' => 'serial',
    'unsigned' => TRUE,
    'not null' => TRUE,
  ),
  'old_id' => array(
    'description' => 'The old id.',
    'type' => 'int',
    'unsigned' => TRUE,
    'not null' => TRUE,
  ),
  'Comments' => array(
    'description' => 'Add comment for table.',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 200,
    'not null' => FALSE,
  ),
 ),
 'primary key' => array('id'),
 'mysql_engine' => 'MyISAM',
 );
 return $schema;
}
```